# How to start a new project in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I just start to learn Swift and have little background in programming.

I am trying to use Swift to make a to-do list. Before starting a new project in Swift, I deleted the previous to-do project, which I use objective-c to write.

I used the same name as the project name and the path is the same (on the Desktop).

After I put several new views on the storyboard, I run it. It turns out to be the old project, even though I have deleted the old files completely[empty the trash can].

You see I add no entry in the table view. 
[image]

but after run it, I get [image]

These static entries are from my previous project.

I just wonder how I can get rid of my previous project.

Any helps will be appreciated!

Comment: BTW, how to change the size of my photo added in my post?

Comment: have you not reset the simulator, perhaps?

Comment: @holex I just tried, but nothing changed. It still gave me the previous todolist.

Comment: When I stimulate my current project, it log "2014-07-14 11:29:42.384 ToDoList[1420:31024] Unknown class XYZToDoListTableViewController in Interface Builder file."  But this customized viewcontroller is from my previous project.

Comment: Resize the screenshot you've taken using a photo editing tool and upload the resized picture.

Comment: I don't know why this community downvote my question. Perhaps, as a beginner and non-English speaker, I wasn't able to interpret my question precisely enough. 

But I finally find out the answers by myself, and I appreciate those two answers in my post. 

just Product->Clean, then problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered the question yourself. Clearly the problem is that you have remnants of your old program, so start a new project with a different name. You probably deleted references to your old files, but did not delete the files themselves. Xcode is great about dragging & dropping in files from other projects, or just copy & paste the relevant code from this project into a new one. Also, the Xcode Beta is a little buggy, so a restarting Xcode, or even a good old-fashion re-boot can never hurt. I've gotten Xcode into a couple funky states that required killing it and re-starting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As a noob, I even don't know how to search my problem on google. This "simple" question (for those who downvote my question) have bothered me for 2 days. Fortunately, after I posted my question here, I found a friend who solved the problem for me.